# For any positive integers $a$ and $b$, the number $(36a+b)(a+36b)$ can never be a power of $2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

APMO 1998:

> Show that for any positive integers $a$ and $b$, the number
>   $(36a+b)(a+36b)$ can never be a power of $2$.

The solution I've read substitutes $a=2^Ap,b=2^Bq$ where $p$ and $q$ are odd positive integers and derives a contradiction.But is my method correct?

**EDIT:** The method below has some incompleteness.Please refer to Andre Nicolas' answer below to know what else I should have mentioned.In brief,I forgot to think(and mention in my solution) why the descent should occur in the first place.

**My method:** $$(36a+b)(a+36b)=2^m$$

This implies that $$36a+b=2^K$$,$$36b+a=2^L$$ Clearly,$a$ and $b$ both must be even.Let $a=2a'$ and $b=2b'$. Substituting these in the two equations,we obtain similar equations $$36a'+b'=2^{K-1}$$ and $$36b'+a'=2^{L-1}$$ By the method of infinite descent,can we now conclude that there are no solutions to the  above two equations?

P.S:The above assumes that  $a$ and $b$ aren't both $2$.

Comment: Yes, nicely done!

Comment: @AndréNicolas,thanks,I hope Fermat will be proud.

Comment: Note that if a=b then 37 becomes a factor of the product as a minor addendum to the proof.

Comment: @AndréNicolas,Neil's answer  seems to be suggesting that since the power of RHS will reach zero and hence the right side will be odd,my argument of $a',b'$ being odd won't work here.

Comment: That answer is not correct. The initial $a$ and $b$ are by assumption positive integers. So $36a_n+b_n$ and its mate are $\ge 37$ during the process, and are powers of $2$, so of course they are not $2^0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas,oh of course.Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice proof!  This kind of proof, an "infinite" construction based on an assumption that is false (and that we *want* to prove false), can be misunderstood. So it is useful to make the steps fully explicit. We give three ways of doing so, the last of which is descent.

**1:** Fermat's Method of Infinite Descent is, essentially, induction, in the form of what is often called the **least number principle**: Any non-empty set of non-negative integers has a smallest element.

Suppose then that there exists a a non-negative integer $u$ for which there are positive integers $x$ and $y$, such that $(36x+y)(x+36y)=2^u$.  Then there is a least such integer. Call it $k$. Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that 
$$(36a+b)(a+36b)=2^k.\tag{1}$$
In (1), the product of two integers $36a+b$ and $a+36b$ is a power of $2$. Thus each of $36a+b$ and $a+36b$ is a power of $2$. Since each of $36a+b$ and $a+36b$ is $\ge 37$, each is is a power of $2$ that is $\ge 2^6$.

In particular, $36a+b$ and $a+36b$ are each even. It follows that $a$ and $b$ are even.

Let $a=2a_1$ and $b=2b_1$. Then $36a+b=2(36a_1+b_1)$ and $a+36b=2(a_1+36b_1)$. It follows that $(36a_1+b_1)(a_1+36b_1)=2^{k-2}$. It is clear that $k-2$ is non-negative. (Indeed $(k-2)\ge 12$.) This contradicts the supposed minimality  of $k$.

---

**2:** One can also rephrase the proof as a **conventional induction** proof. We want to show that for all non-negative integers $n$, there are no positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $(36a+b)(a+36b)=2^n$. The result is trivial to verify for $n=0$ and $n=1$. Next we prove the induction step, that if the result is true at $n=k-2$, then the result is true at $n=k$.

Suppose to the contrary that $(36a+b)(a+36b)=2^k$. Arguing exactly like above, we show that there exist $a_1$ and $b_1$ such that $(36a_1+b_1)(a_1+36b_1)=2^{k-2}$, contradicting the induction assumption.

---

**3:** *Infinite Descent* uses exactly the same arithmetical observations, but the packaging is different. Let us suppose that there are positive integers $a_0,b_0$ and a non-negative $k_0$ such that  $(36a_0+b_0)(a_0+36b_0)=2^{k_0}$.

By the argument described in detail above,  there exist positive integers $a_1,b_1$ and a non-negative $k_1\lt k_0$ such that $(36a_1+b_1)(a_1+36b_1)=2^{k_1}$.

But then there exist positive integers $a_2,b_2$ and a non-negative $k_2\lt k_1$ such that $(36a_2+b_2)(a_2+36b_2)=2^{k_2}$. And so on, forever.

Thus there exists an infinite descending sequence $k_0\gt k_1\gt k_2\gt \cdots$ of non-negative integers. But there cannot be such a sequence, so we have reached a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.So the argument I used did not use infinite descent,but only used its main ideas?

Comment: Your argument mentioned Infinite Descent. You did not bother to make the descent explicit. (I did, in the very last section of the answer.) But I would say yours is an Infinite Descent argument. Although the descent was not absolutely explicit, it was clear enough to anyone who knows descent and reads your argument.

Comment: @rah4927 Andre: While I agree that a reader who has mastered descent can easily infer the missing steps, I strongly disagree with your assessment that there is "no reason to add" to the OP's sketched proof. When students are first learning descent it is *essential* that their proofs *explicitly* demonstrate that they understand *all* that is required to establish the descent. This has not been achieved in the OP's sketched proof, but this answer misleads the OP into thinking otherwise.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I have taken your comment to heart and modified the introduction.

Comment: @André Thanks! I would write "essential" instead of "useful" in "useful to make the step explicit'. I have seen too many students make errors regarding such, which can lead to erroneous descents.

Comment: @André I agree. In all proofs, judgement of "which steps are so trivial they can be omitted" is highly context dependent. Often on MSE we don't have enough context to make such judgments. In that case I prefer to err on the side of caution, even at the risk of being perceived as too pedantic.

Comment: It depends on context. If I were grading an Olympiad paper, I probably would take off no more than $2$ marks out of $7$ for the lack of steps, in a Problem 1.

Answer (score 1):

that is not a hard question !

$36a^2+36b^2+(36^2+1)ab=36((a+b)^2-2ab)+(36^2+1)ab=36(a+b)^2+(36\cdot34+1)ab=2^n$

$\Longrightarrow$$36(2^Ap+2^Bq)^2+(36\cdot34+1)2^{A+B}pq=2^n$

$\Longrightarrow$$36(p+2^{B-A}q)(q+2^{A-B}p)+(36\cdot34+1)pq=2^m$

$\Longrightarrow$$36\cdot2^{B-A}q^2+36\cdot2^{A-B}p^2+(72+36\cdot34+1)pq=2^m$

$\Longrightarrow$$36\cdot(q^2+p^2)+(72+36\cdot34+1)pq=2^m$

a contradiction holds !

is it helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the infinite descent doesn't work because the one of RHSs will eventually cease (or even initially fail) to be even, as 1 is also a power of two. You need to consider what happens when you reach the cases $36a^*+b^*=2^0$ and/or $36b^*+a^*=2^0$ because then the reasoning $a^*$ and $b^*$ are even breaks down.

Which suggests the original solution which extracts all the powers of two at once might be necessary.

Comment: Andre Nicolas' comment above points out a hole in your reasoning.So I hope you will take down your answer(or add something insightful).

Comment: @rah4927 Neil's critique is correct, since your argument does not *explicitly* show why this cannot occur. if your proof were both *correct* and *complete* you would not need to refer to someone else's comments and answers to complete the proof. Those *essential* details *must* be included in the proof, since they can make-or-break the descent process.

Comment: @BillDubuque,thanks,my argument really is incomplete.Neil's critique(while eventually wrong)  helped me see that my proof should have mentioned why the descent actually occurs in the first place.

Comment: @rah4927 I'm happy to see that you understand the matter. It was clear that you had the correct idea. But *complete* proofs don't leave doubts like that above. Also they convince the reader that you really do understand what is required to completely establish the descent. Forcing yourself to be explicit in simple cases like this will help ensure that you follow the same protocol in more complex cases, where the chances for error are greater.